# Solr Index-Time Document Boosts not working

Tags: search, solr

I can't find any solid documentation on using index-time document boosts, aside from how set the boost and that omitNorms needs to be set to false on the field types you're querying. I'm really at a loss as to what's happening here. (again -- SIMPLE query, no filters or anything else)

Assuming I do a simple search for title:scissor or even just "scissor", I get back 5 results.  If I set a boost of anything between 1.1-1000 on any of these results besides the first result, I would expect this result to have a higher score in the next search.

What's happening to me, however, is that these boosted results are coming back with LOWER scores than before I boosted them, and if I try to boost or negatively boost (0.1-0.9) the top result it NEVER changes position).

For example below, I added a boost of "5" to the fifth result (this is pre-boost):

```
"explain": {
  "File #1": "\n6.312951 = weight(title:scissor in 495641) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  6.312951 = fieldWeight in 495641, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.625902 = idf(docFreq=10, maxDocs=1231567)\n    0.5 = fieldNorm(doc=495641)\n",
  "File #2": "\n5.5238323 = weight(title:scissor in 984389) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  5.5238323 = fieldWeight in 984389, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.625902 = idf(docFreq=10, maxDocs=1231567)\n    0.4375 = fieldNorm(doc=984389)\n",
  "File #3": "\n5.5238323 = weight(title:scissor in 1098172) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  5.5238323 = fieldWeight in 1098172, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.625902 = idf(docFreq=10, maxDocs=1231567)\n    0.4375 = fieldNorm(doc=1098172)\n",
  "File #4": "\n4.7347136 = weight(title:scissor in 901186) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  4.7347136 = fieldWeight in 901186, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.625902 = idf(docFreq=10, maxDocs=1231567)\n    0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=901186)\n",
  "File #5": "\n4.7347136 = weight(title:scissor in 1037808) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  4.7347136 = fieldWeight in 1037808, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.625902 = idf(docFreq=10, maxDocs=1231567)\n    0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=1037808)\n",
  "File #6": "\n4.7347136 = weight(title:scissor in 1044468) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  4.7347136 = fieldWeight in 1044468, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.625902 = idf(docFreq=10, maxDocs=1231567)\n    0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=1044468)\n",
  "File #7": "\n4.4639306 = weight(title:scissor in 972468) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  4.4639306 = fieldWeight in 972468, product of:\n    1.4142135 = tf(freq=2.0), with freq of:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n    12.625902 = idf(docFreq=10, maxDocs=1231567)\n    0.25 = fieldNorm(doc=972468)\n",
  "File #8": "\n3.9455943 = weight(title:scissor in 896318) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  3.9455943 = fieldWeight in 896318, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.625902 = idf(docFreq=10, maxDocs=1231567)\n    0.3125 = fieldNorm(doc=896318)\n",
  "File #9": "\n3.9455943 = weight(title:scissor in 1037733) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  3.9455943 = fieldWeight in 1037733, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.625902 = idf(docFreq=10, maxDocs=1231567)\n    0.3125 = fieldNorm(doc=1037733)\n",
  "File #10": "\n3.1564755 = weight(title:scissor in 1045578) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  3.1564755 = fieldWeight in 1045578, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.625902 = idf(docFreq=10, maxDocs=1231567)\n    0.25 = fieldNorm(doc=1045578)\n"
},
```

And now the fifth result has become the sixth result:

```
"explain": {
  "File #1": "\n6.269446 = weight(title:scissor in 495641) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  6.269446 = fieldWeight in 495641, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.538892 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1231568)\n    0.5 = fieldNorm(doc=495641)\n",
  "File #2": "\n5.485765 = weight(title:scissor in 984389) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  5.485765 = fieldWeight in 984389, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.538892 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1231568)\n    0.4375 = fieldNorm(doc=984389)\n",
  "File #3": "\n5.485765 = weight(title:scissor in 1098172) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  5.485765 = fieldWeight in 1098172, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.538892 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1231568)\n    0.4375 = fieldNorm(doc=1098172)\n",
  "File #4": "\n4.7020845 = weight(title:scissor in 901186) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  4.7020845 = fieldWeight in 901186, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.538892 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1231568)\n    0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=901186)\n",
  "File #6": "\n4.7020845 = weight(title:scissor in 1044468) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  4.7020845 = fieldWeight in 1044468, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.538892 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1231568)\n    0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=1044468)\n",
  "File #5": "\n4.7020845 = weight(title:scissor in 0) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  4.7020845 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.538892 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1231568)\n    0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=0)\n",
  "File #7": "\n4.4331675 = weight(title:scissor in 972468) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  4.4331675 = fieldWeight in 972468, product of:\n    1.4142135 = tf(freq=2.0), with freq of:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n    12.538892 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1231568)\n    0.25 = fieldNorm(doc=972468)\n",
  "File #8": "\n3.9184036 = weight(title:scissor in 896318) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  3.9184036 = fieldWeight in 896318, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.538892 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1231568)\n    0.3125 = fieldNorm(doc=896318)\n",
  "File #9": "\n3.9184036 = weight(title:scissor in 1037733) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  3.9184036 = fieldWeight in 1037733, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.538892 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1231568)\n    0.3125 = fieldNorm(doc=1037733)\n",
  "File #10": "\n3.134723 = weight(title:scissor in 1045578) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  3.134723 = fieldWeight in 1045578, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.538892 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1231568)\n    0.25 = fieldNorm(doc=1045578)\n"
},
```

Specifically, the before/after of the result in question:

```
"File #5": "\n4.7347136 = weight(title:scissor in 1037808) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  4.7347136 = fieldWeight in 1037808, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.625902 = idf(docFreq=10, maxDocs=1231567)\n    0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=1037808)\n",

"File #5": "\n4.7020845 = weight(title:scissor in 0) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:\n  4.7020845 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    12.538892 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1231568)\n    0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=0)\n",
```

Any assistance in explaining to me what's happening here would be greatly appreciated. I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are setting the boost?  From my limited experience, the boost should be present in the explain, but it is not appearing.  Also, I believe that your observation about File #5 moving down a ranking does not represent a real problem.  The scores of documents #4-6 are all the same.  Therefore, without an additional sort specified, there is no reason to believe that the sort order of these three documents relative to each other would be deterministic.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, it would be good to have a project on github with all the relevant configuration files, or you may include that in your question.